# Selecting the maximum matched pairs

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, deep-learning, medical

I have two groups with different IDs, I got the possible matches by running a code that looked into cases that achieved the criteria, however, it returned for example for one ID from Group A, I have more than one match from Group B.  I would like to get rid of the repetition and choose the matched pair randomly that achieved the maximum number of matched pairs at the end.  Any Idea of how to solve this?

Here is my code:

```
SH = readtable('contol_parameters.xlsx','Sheet','m');
%% check if crieria met 
numElementsX = length(rmmissing(SH.Ages1));
numElementsY = length(rmmissing(SH.Ages2));
U1 = [];
U2=  [];
 for r=1:numElementsX
    for s=1:numElementsY
        if (abs(rmmissing(SH.Ages1(r))-rmmissing(SH.Ages2(s)))<=10) && (abs(rmmissing(SH.vol_1(r))-rmmissing(SH.vol_2(s)))<=10)
            U1(end+1)= SH.ID1(r);
            U2(end+1)= SH.ID2(s);
        end
    end
 end

%generated list 
 U_TS=[U1', U2'];

%results 

Group A Group B
216 217
216 221
216 222
216 234
216 256
216 262
216 266
216 330
216 390
225 217
225 222
225 234
225 239
225 256
225 257
225 260
225 263
225 266
225 277
225 302
225 324
225 330
225 333
225 341
225 359
225 381
225 386
225 390
225 423
225 435
225 436
225 442
225 466
225 470
225 478
227 257
227 260
227 263
227 277
227 302
```

Comment: You are more likely to get help if you include a minimal code snippet that can be run (define all variables) and explicitly include what the desired output would be. The part I find most confusing is when you say "randomly". Do you mean try many times and keep the best matching? Also, what's the typical input size? That can limit (or advise) the use of brute-force-ish approaches

Comment: Each row of data contains matched pair. For example subject 216, has 10 corresponding pairs which might be also suitable for other subjects from group A.  I would like to select a subject from group B that has less chance to be used by the subject in group A, so in the end, we end up with the largest number of matched pairs. By randomly, I mean Subject 216 can be paired with any of the first 10 rows in group B (check the main question) with a restriction that chosen subject from group B has less chance to be used by other subjects from group A.

Comment: Let me see if I understand the question: (1) You start with two lists of "subjects", and an operation that identifies "compatible" pairs. (2) You are currently identifying all subject pairs `[A_i, B_i]` such that the pair is "compatible". (3) Now you would like to find shorter list of pairs, such that each subject is only a member of one pair. Is this about right? (For example, this could be a dating matchmaking function, where we are trying to maximize the number of compatible romantic pairs, with no overlaps.)

Comment: Exactly! :) based on my code written above, it generated all possible pair for each element in A which might be also suitable for other elements in A. I want to choose the pairs in such a way that no one in A is left without pair or at least it achieved the maximum number of pairs.

Comment: I finally reached a solution! and it worked well using ismember()  SH = readtable('contol_parameters.xlsx','Sheet','m');
numElementsX = length(rmmissing(SH.Ages1));
numElementsY = length(rmmissing(SH.Ages2));
U1 = [];
U2=  [];
 for r=1:numElementsX
    for s=1:numElementsY if ismember(SH.ID1(r), U1)== 0 && ismember(SH.ID2(s), U2)== 0  if (abs(rmmissing(SH.Ages1(r))-rmmissing(SH.Ages2(s)))<=10) && (abs(rmmissing(SH.vol_1(r))-rmmissing(SH.vol_2(s)))<=10)
            U1(end+1)= SH.ID1(r);
            U2(end+1)= SH.ID2(s);
        end
    end
 end
 U_TS=[U1', U2'];

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your objective I would try the following:

```
uA = unique(A);
uB = unique(B);
iCnt = zeros(length(uA),length(uB);
for ii = 1:length(uA)
    for jj = 1:length(uB)
         iCnt(ii,jj) = sum((A==uA(ii) & B==uB(jj));
    end
end
[~,ind] = sort(sum(iCnt),'ascend');
uB = uB(ind);
iCnt = iCnt(:,ind);

%you now have a matrix (iCnt) where the least common members of groupB will be in the leftmost columns of iCnt and for each row (which represents the unique members of GroupA in vector uA) you can find the first non-zero column of iCnt to pick the least common member of GroupB. If that member of B has already been selected previously, you could go to the next non-zero column for another candidate
```

Comment: Many thanks let me try it and let you know.

Comment: Thank you., so the code resulted in a matrix of zeros and ones with a size of  20*5 without displaying the matched pairs. I would like to make sure that when using unique(), the corresponding pairs are not assigned to another element. for example element #217 has a certain number of matches from B so its pair should be one of these. Also, the pair elements in B should not be used again with another element in A. Quiet complicated :(

Comment: I finally reached a solution! and it worked well using ismember()  SH = readtable('contol_parameters.xlsx','Sheet','m');
numElementsX = length(rmmissing(SH.Ages1));
numElementsY = length(rmmissing(SH.Ages2));
U1 = [];
U2=  [];
 for r=1:numElementsX
    for s=1:numElementsY if ismember(SH.ID1(r), U1)== 0 && ismember(SH.ID2(s), U2)== 0  if (abs(rmmissing(SH.Ages1(r))-rmmissing(SH.Ages2(s)))<=10) && (abs(rmmissing(SH.vol_1(r))-rmmissing(SH.vol_2(s)))<=10)
            U1(end+1)= SH.ID1(r);
            U2(end+1)= SH.ID2(s);
        end
    end
 end
 U_TS=[U1', U2'];